# Upgrade Max OSX 10.6.8 on VMWare

Tags: macos, upgrade, vmware, osx-snow-leopard

I installed a Mac 10.6.8 on VMWare sometime ago just to get a feel of OSX, I want to know what is the best way to upgrade my OSX 10.6.8 to upgrade to the latest version on VMWare

I am using VMware Work Station on Windows 7. The VMWare version is 10.0.1. Please help

Comment: Hey, I don't know where to ask the VMware related questions, :-/ I tried to find a community but couldn't

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean, how to upgrade to the latest version of OS X, AKA "Yosemite" or OS X 10.10, right?  You need to do this:

- First, find out if your VMWare instance can run OS X Yosemite.
- Back up your current installation.
- Get OS X Yosemite from the Mac App
  Store.
- Double-click Install OS X Yosemite to begin installation.

Comment: "find out if your VMWare instance can run OS X Yosemite." How can I find this out?

Comment: Look on VMWare's website under "software requirements", e.g. https://www.vmware.com/support/fusion/faq/requirements, or look in the documentation for your software.  Be sure to check the requirements for the version of VMWare you are running.